# Asymptotic estimate of the form $k=C\log\log n$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, asymptotics

Suppose that we have
$$
n=k^{\frac{1}{\beta}k^22^{k+12}\log\frac 1{\alpha}}
$$
where $\alpha,\beta\in(0,1)$. It is claimed that
$$
k\sim C\log\log n
$$
for some constant $C=C(\alpha,\beta)$. How do one deduce such an estimate?

I am totally lost here, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume logarithms in base $2$. This would not change anything anyway, besides constants.*

First, note that
$$
n=k^{\frac{1}{\beta}k^22^{k+12}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}
= 2^{\frac{1}{\beta}k^22^{k+12}\log\frac{1}{\alpha} \log k}
= 2^{\frac{2^{12}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\beta}k^22 ^{k} \log k}
$$
so
$$
\log n = \frac{2^{12}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\beta}\cdot k^22 ^{k} \log k
= C'\cdot 2 ^{k + 2\log k+\log\log k}
$$
setting $C'\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{2^{12}\log\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\beta}$.

Taking the logarithm again, we get
$$
\log\log n = k + 2\log k+\log\log k + O(1)
$$
and, when $k\to\infty$, the right-hand side satisfies $$k + 2\log k+\log\log k + O(1)\operatorname*{\sim}_{k\to\infty} k$$
which implies
$$
\log\log n\operatorname*{\sim}_{k\to\infty} k.
$$

Comment: Yes you are right, it is actually $\log\frac 1{\alpha}$.

Comment: So $C(\alpha,\beta)$ is really independent of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? At first I arrive at something very similar but I thought I was wrong since I got $C=1$.

Comment: As far as I can tell: you are only looking at the first-order term, so yes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Anyway, I'm just curious as to what you meant by "first order term". What does it mean to calculate an asymptotic to the, says, second order?

Comment: Think of it as an approximation of the form $f(x) \sim_{x\to\infty} x$. This is the first term; you can also write it  $f(x) = x + o(x)$, or $\frac{f(x)-x}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0$. But you good tdo an expansion of that sort to lower order terms: e.g., $f(x) = x+\sqrt{x} + o(\log x)$ (meaning $\frac{f(x)-(x+\sqrt{x})}{\log x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} 0$ "the function $f$ is well-approximated at $\infty$ by the simpler function $x+\sqrt{x}$, and the remaining term is negligible in front of $\log x$".